# Is it standard behavior for this code to throw a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, lejos-nxj

I've had a big problem in some library code, which I've pinned down to a single statement:

```
System.out.println((String) null);
```

Ok, the code doesn't actually look like that, but it certainly calls `println` with a null argument. Doing this causes my whole applicaio to throw an unexpected `NullPointerException`.

In general, should `println` throw this exception under that circumstance, or is this non-standard behavior due to a poor implementation of the `out` instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JVM of sun prints simply "null". This is the specified behavior of [`PrintStream.print(String)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print%28java.lang.String%29) when given a `null` argument.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, found the error, in my platform's implementation of `PrintStream.print`. I guess I'll follow it up with the developers.

```
public void print(String s) {
    // WHERE IS THE NULL CHECK??!
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++) {
        write(s.charAt(i));
    }
}
```

Thanks for confirming that this is indeed non-standard behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

That above shouldn't throw an exception. Are you sure you don't have something like:

```
System.out.println(a.b);
```

where `a` is `null` ?

Alternatively, perhaps your `System.out` has been set to null (not many people realise that you can set the `out`/`err` streams)?

Comment: No, I ran that code on its own, on my platform, and it threw a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

When I try that line on standard desktop Java (Java SE 6 update 20 on Mac OS X), it does not throw a `NullPointerException`, it just prints `null`.

I think that throwing a `NullPointerException` is a bug in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried running this on sun's jdk 6 and it worked just fine.  It printed null as expected.